# removeChild and then add again previously removedChild to reload and clean it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to do something like this

```
     var refresh = function(){
                  var elem = document.getElementById(scope.id);
                       elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                    console.log('Canvas Destroyed');
               //Here I would like to add removedChild again so i am sure that is clean//
               };



           scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) {

                    if (newVal) {

                        refresh(); //I Use Function Here So i am sure that canvas are empty

                        var newChart = document.getElementById(scope.id).getContext("2d");
                        console.log('Charts0');
                        var PieChart = new Chart(newChart).Pie(scope.data, scope.options);
                        console.log('Charts1');
                    }

                }, true);
```

Question: It is possible to first remove element and then put the same element back in one function? Or reload canvas or reboot so it will be without any data when creating charts in it. My application is dynamic and if i will not do it, some highlighting layers from my charts will overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function removeAndAdd(el){
    var next = el.nextSibling;
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(el);
    //Do stuff to el
    parent.insertBefore(el, next);
}
```